# How to style the datatables length select element using Select2

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the jquery datatables plugin with the jquery Select2 plugin.  I tried overriding the css class with my own class but it didn't work.  It still shows up with the default OS / browser style.

Answer (score 3):

For an earlier event, use `preInit`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var dataTable = $('#datatables').DataTable({
  //your datatables settings
  });
});

$(document).on( 'preInit.dt', function (settings, json) {
    $('div.dataTables_length select').select2();
});
```

This way, your select is started before the init event on datatables is completed... If there is a delay because you are loading data via Ajax, this is probably better.

https://datatables.net/reference/event/preInit

Answer (score 1):

Call select2 on the select element after the table has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

   // load datatable
   jQuery('#data_table').dataTable({
    ....do settings and other stuff
   });

   $('div.dataTables_length select').select2();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use DataTables' `fnInitComplete` callback, which is called when DataTables has been initialized. See the [Callbacks](https://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) page in their documentation.

Here is an example extending the DataTable defaults to accomplish this:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  "bPaginate": true,                /* just an example. can be false or removed altogether */
  "bLengthChange": true,            /* another example. */

  /* ... other options ... */

  "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
    $(".dataTables_length .select2").select2({ 
      /* select2 options, as an example */
      minimumResultsForSearch: -1 
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: If you do that , the select element will first show without styling and only switch to select2 after data has been loaded in the table. In my case, with an Ajax request, it's too late and you can see unstyled select for a few milliseconds...